# Error: Append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have so far:

```
seasons = ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"]
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
combined = []

for s in seasons:
  for m in months:
    combined.append(months[0:2] , "is in the season " , seasons[3])
    combined.append(months[3:5] , "is in the season " , seasons[0])
    combined.append(months[6:8] , "is in the season" , seasons[2])
    combined.append(months[9:11] , "is in season" , seasons[0])
```

I am getting an error that says append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
I somewhat understand what this error means but have no clue how to fix it, does anyone have a fix, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's not the right way to do this operation.  Your loops are pointless, since you aren't using the loop variables.  I will try to show you below.

Comment: `months[0:2] , "is in the season " , seasons[3]` is not the correct way to construct a string.
You seem to have been confused by the behavior of `print()`

Comment: It means `append` only takes one argument. It's not like `print` which implicitly combines multiple arguments into a single string.

Comment: What do you want to achive? `append` take 1 argument so your code will not work.

Comment: @chepner _technically_ `print()` doesn't combine multiple arguments into a single string. It just prints each of them one after the other

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I know, but close enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way to get your 12 entries:

```
seasons = ["Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"]
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
combined = []

for i,s in enumerate(seasons):
    for m in months[i*3:i*3+3]:
        combined.append( m + " is in the season " + s )
print(combined)
```

Output:

```
['January is in the season Winter', 'February is in the season Winter', 'March is in the season Winter', 'April is in the season Spring', 'May is in the season Spring', 'June is in the season Spring', 'July is in the season Summer', 'August is in the season Summer', 'September is in the season Summer', 'October is in the season Fall', 'November is in the season Fall', 'December is in the season Fall']
```

Comment: Now YOU need to figure out how to print those as per the assignment (which is easy), then do the shuffle, reverse, and print again.

Comment: thank you for the help I have completed the assignment but I was wondering how [i*3:i*3+3] part works and why those specific numbers are used?

Comment: Did you do the math?  Season #0 needs months 0, 1, 2.  Season #1 needs months 3, 4, 5.  So, we need months starting with season x 3 and ending just before (season x 3 + 3).  That's `[i*3 : i*3+3]`.

Answer (score 0):

`months[0:2] , "is in the season " , seasons[3]` is not the correct way to construct a string.
You seem to have been confused by the behavior of `print()`

Instead, you want to *construct a string first*, and then `append()` that string to your list.

```
def make_string(months, season):
    p1 = ", ".join(months)
    return p1 + " is in the season " + season
```

Here, we create `p1` by joining all the elements of the sequence `months` with a comma. Then, we append the string literal and the season to it, and return that value. To use this function:

```
s = make_string(months[0:2], seasons[3])
combined.append(s)

s = make_string(months[3:5], seasons[0])
combined.append(s)

s = make_string(months[6:8], seasons[1])
combined.append(s)

s = make_string(months[9:11], seasons[2])
combined.append(s)
```

Which gives:

```
combined = ['January, February is in the season Winter',
 'April, May is in the season Spring',
 'July, August is in the season Summer',
 'October, November is in the season Fall']
```

Note that you don't need a loop because you never use the loop variable

Comment: Again, although this technically eliminates the error he got, this contributes nothing towards solving his actual problem.  That list is not what he needs.

Comment: @Tim then he should ask about the actual problem and be more clear about what he wants. OP hasn't specified an expected output, only that the appropriate months need to go with the appropriate seasons (this is why [ask] should be required reading for new users). Since OP has used syntax that indicates that they converted this code to do `.append()` instead of `print()`, I figured they saw the output they get from `print()` and found it to be acceptable, and then tried to use `list.append()` and asked the question when they see the error

Comment: @TimRoberts if we do the whole assignment then the OP will be unemployable (unable to program). Teachers don't get students to do assignments because the copier is broken, but because they want the student to learn.

Comment: It's a tough line to draw.  They posted a question on this assignment earlier today with no code at all, so we can see they've made at least some progress on their own